# NullPointerException - Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

I received the below message from logcat when attempting to run my application. Essentially I am trying to retrieve a list of information from parse using query. The code seems fine, so I am not too sure how to resolve this issue.

Logcat Message

```
 08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 7112
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.usermatch}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1.<init>(Fragment1.java:77)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.dooba.beta.usermatch.initialisePaging(usermatch.java:31)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.dooba.beta.usermatch.onCreate(usermatch.java:24)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     ... 11 more
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1.<init>(Fragment1.java:77)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.dooba.beta.usermatch.initialisePaging(usermatch.java:31)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at com.dooba.beta.usermatch.onCreate(usermatch.java:24)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-25 05:40:03.605: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     ... 11 more
```

Activity portion code

```
 query1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {

                for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                    // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                            .getObjectId());
                    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
                    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
                    query.setLimit(1);
                    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
                    // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
                    // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);

                    mUserNameRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);

                    mUserNameRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Name").toString()); 

                    final String userRetrieveName = mUserNameRetrieved.getText().toString();

                    Button newPage = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnMatchConfirm);
                    newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                            currentUser.put("UserMatchName", userRetrieveName);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), matchOptionActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });


                }
    }//for loop
            });
```

Update

Update 2

Update 3

```
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 8520
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.usermatch}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1.<init>(Fragment1.java:78)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at com.dooba.beta.usermatch.initialisePaging(usermatch.java:31)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at com.dooba.beta.usermatch.onCreate(usermatch.java:24)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-25 14:20:17.143: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     ... 11 more
```

Update 3 code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    private ArrayList<String> headline;
    private ArrayList<String> activityname;

    protected TextView mUserRetrieved;
    protected TextView mUserActivityNameRetrieved;
    protected TextView mUserAgeRetrieved;
    protected TextView mUserHeadlineRetrieved;



    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber(
            "Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
            "Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");
    TextView mUserNameRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        final String userRetrieveName = mUserNameRetrieved.getText().toString();
        Button newPage = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnMatchConfirm);
        newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                currentUser.put("UserMatchName", userRetrieveName);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), matchOptionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);






        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        age = new ArrayList<String>();
        headline = new ArrayList<String>();
        activityname = new ArrayList<String>();

        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");


        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query1 = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query1.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query1.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query1.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query1.setLimit(1);
        query1.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query1.orderByDescending("Name");

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query11 = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query11.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query11.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query11.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query11.setLimit(1);
        query11.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query11.orderByDescending("Name");

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query4 = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query4.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query4.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query4.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query4.setLimit(1);
        query4.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age",

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query5 = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query5.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query5.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query5.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query5.setLimit(1);
        query5.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age",

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");




        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {

                for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                    // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                            .getObjectId());
                    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
                    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
                    query.setLimit(1);
                    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
                    // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
                    // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
                    query.orderByDescending("Name");

                    ParseFile image = objects.get(i).getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


                    ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureresult);

                     // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
                     // data.
                     imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
                     imageView.setParseFile(image);
                     imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                       @Override
                       public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                           if (data != null) {
                               Log.i("ParseImageView", "Fetched: " + data.length);
                             } else {
                               Log.e("ParseImageView", "Error fetching: " + e.getMessage());
                             }
                       }


                 });
                }
    }//for loop
            });


        query1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {

                for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                    // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                            .getObjectId());
                    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
                    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
                    query.setLimit(1);
                    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
                    // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
                    // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);

                    mUserNameRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);

                    mUserNameRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Name").toString()); 




                }
    }//for loop
            });

        query11.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {

                for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                    // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                            .getObjectId());
                    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
                    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
                    query.setLimit(1);
                    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
                    // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
                    // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);

                    mUserHeadlineRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistheadline);

                    mUserHeadlineRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Headline").toString()); 



                }
    }//for loop
            });




            query4.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {

                    for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                        // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                                .getObjectId());
                        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
                        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
                        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
                        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
                        query.setLimit(1);
                        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
                        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
                        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);

                        mUserActivityNameRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistactivityname);

                        mUserActivityNameRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("ActivityName").toString()); 




                    }
        }//for loop
                });

            query5.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {

                    for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                        // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                                .getObjectId());
                        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
                        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
                        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
                        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
                        query.setLimit(1);
                        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
                        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
                        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);

                        mUserAgeRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistage);

                        mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Age").toString()); 



                    }
        }//for loop
                });


    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code from `com.dooba.beta.Fragment1.<init>(Fragment1.java:77)` This is where the NPE comes from.

Comment: String userRetrieveName = mUserNameRetrieved.getText().toString();

Comment: did you debug to see if whether mUserNameRetrieved or mUserNameRetrieved.getText() was null ?

Answer (score 2):

The field `mUserNameRetrieved` is never initialized in `Fragment1` so it is null if you call `getText()`.

Comment: initialized it to what?

Comment: @user3907211 it must be a `TextView` `(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added     TextView mUserNameRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);
 but for some reason the error persist

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. I have added the updated code under the update 2 section of my initial post

Comment: @user3907211 is a filed with this id defined in the xml file belongsto the fragment? can you put `userRetrieveName = mUserNameRetrieved.getText().toString();
` to `OnCreateView` of your fragment  ond only declare it at the begining?

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. I have unfortunatetly encountered another null point exception error while trying to run this. I have added the updated logcat and code under update 3 section of my initial post.

Comment: @user3907211 In which line?

Answer (score 1):

Your `mUserNameRetrieved` variable is not receiving any value. Try to `SysOut` its value or put some condition check so that if it will not receive any value then it will not give an error(use condition only if required).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is that it is suppose to return a value giving that the textfield is populating data from Parse, and then I would want to take that data (name) and store it into Parse under a new column

Comment: looks like `mUserNameRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Name").toString()); 
` is causing problem. Have you checked it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I have checked it and have played around the code to receive a new nullpointer error. I have updated the new logcat message and update code under the update section of my initial post.